# How to bypass Cognito authorizer on AWS API Gateway proxy resource for CORS preflight requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, cors, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have a very simple API Gateway resource config:

[image: API Gateway Resource COnfig]

The `ANY` method points to a `node.js` lambda running `express.js`. Express.js then takes care of routing, CORS requests, etc. The API will be consumed by a single-page javascript application.

Almost all of the endpoints need to be authorized, so I added a `Cognito` authorizer to the `ANY` method. This setup however breaks CORS preflight requests, because preflight requests cannot carry `Authorization` header.

1. How can I make preflight requests bypass the `Cognito` authorizer?
2. Optionally, how can I make a few selected endpoints bypass `Cognito` authorizer (for GET)?
3. Is there any solution to the above except having to duplicate all my routing in the API Gateway resource designer?

*The only solution I can think of is using Application Load Balancer instead of API Gateway, and writing my own Cognito authorizer inside the lambda function.*

*Another solution may be using [cognito-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cognito-express) instead of the AWS-provided Cognito authorizer. However I would naturally prefer the AWS-provided authorizer for security reasons.*

Comment: Are you using proxy or non-proxy integration?

Comment: @kgiannakakis proxy integration

Comment: Try adding an OPTIONS request before the ANY request.

Comment: @kgiannakakis isn't that gonna affect just that single resource rather than applying to all subresources?

Comment: what was the solution? is there any answer ?

Comment: @micronyks I don't think there is a solution. The workaround that I went with is `cognito-express`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `ANY` method with an authorizer and expect OPTIONS to be CORS preflight compatible. Just create the individual methods you need on the resource (`GET`, `POST` etc...) let it inherit the authorizer setting then create the `OPTIONS` method and explicitly set the authorizer to none.

Comment: That sounds like the point 3) in my question.

Comment: @Paya ah wasn’t sure what that meant what you meant. You should be maintaining things in IaC like cloudformation or CDK.

Comment: Agreed on CDK, yet that still requires either duplicating the routing (this time in CDK) or abandoning the expressjs/proxy-resource design and using a dedicated lambda per endpoint. Nevertheless, it seems the `cognito-express` that I discovered later works fine and enables the desired design. Although it is less than ideal as I would much rather reuse the "builtin" AWS authorizer if possible.